# Got the checkout of project, wont open in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, tortoisesvn

I have got the project of checkout of [VuDroid](https://code.google.com/p/vudroid/source/checkout) from code.google; then I wanted to do some changes in that as I wanted to modify it according to needs of my project but I can't open it in Eclipse. I tried to import it as "open as existing project" but it says it can't find a project in that directory. Am I doing it wrong or what?

Answer (score 2):

There's a `pom.xml` file in the project, which suggests it's a Maven-based project. Import it from Eclipse as `"File > Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects"`. Make sure you have all the Eclipse-Maven related plugins installed, or install them on-the-fly when Eclipse prompts you to do so.